# Objdump -S does not show the source code listing of Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, linux-device-driver, disassembly

I am trying to debug a crash from one of my kernel module ; I am trying to get source code listing along with output of objdump but it is not listing. Is there something I am missing ?

```
 mips-linux-objdump -S <filename.o> > temp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely either a) all debugging information was stripped off the kernel module object file at some point during the build or b) even if the debugging information is there, `objdump` can't locate the source code files, in which case you might try to `cd` to where the source files are before running `objdump`.

Comment: I have checked the Makefiles inside my module, there was no optimization flag defined. I have added -g option to gcc inside my makefile. Not sure about the linker file for each kernel module and where to find it as I have not defined any linker file specific to my module. Looks like a) seems to be the reason why C file is not getting listed but not sure how to enable it in Linux kernel module build ? Any help.

Comment: Thanks. I could enable the -g option in Kernel Makefile and then get the C source code list in objdump.

Comment: Usually you are not supposed to touch Makefiles in the linux kernel. `make CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y` should help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile your kernel module with the debug information to have the interleaved source code in the dumped output. Recompile your kernel module with `-g -ggdb` for `CFLAGS`.

Comment: What's this `-gdb` option?

Comment: @Clément it's a typo, it's `-ggdb`, answer edited. For documentation of the `-ggdb` option https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

Comment: Thanks for the update; I reversed my downvote into an upvote :)